# CreateProcess: redirect child stdout to parent stdout in C++/Windows

Tags: c++, windows

According to MSDN this redirects child stdout to parent stdout, but it does not, what is wrong?

```
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
   STARTUPINFOA si;

   ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
   si.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
   si.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
   si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

   BOOL ret = CreateProcessA( 0, cmd_line, 0, 0, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, & si, & pi);
```

using DuplicateHandle does not help:

```
HANDLE out, err;//global variables
...
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFOA si;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );  
BOOL ret = DuplicateHandle( GetCurrentProcess(), GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),  GetCurrentProcess(), &out, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);//todo check ret
ret = DuplicateHandle( GetCurrentProcess(), GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE),  GetCurrentProcess(), &err, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);//todo check ret

si.hStdOutput = out;
si.hStdError = err;
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

ret = CreateProcessA( 0, cmd_line, 0, 0, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, & si, & pi);
```

Comment: Could you give the MSDN link you are using?

Comment: This is my code, there's no example on MSDN, just documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: On a side note... the A functions don't always do what they say they are supposed to do and are not really supported (see Michael Kaplan's [blog for more details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/)) I would highly suggest using the W version instead.

Comment: The child process gets a copy of the parent's standard handles *by default* so this exercise appears completely pointless.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: "Console handles can be duplicated for use only in the same process." from MSDN's comments on DuplicateHandle.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BOOL ret = CreateProcessA( 0, cmd_line, 0, 0, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, & si, & pi);`

**CREATE_NO_WINDOW** causes this behavior, remove it:

`BOOL ret = CreateProcessA( 0, cmd_line, 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, & si, & pi);`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I second Michael's advice. You shouldn't be using the A versions at all, ever again, unless for some crazy reason you need to support Windows 98. Hint: You don't. You should only ever be using the W versions. Always `#define UNICODE`!!!

According to the documentation:

> `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` `0x00000100`  The `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, and
>   `hStdError members` contain additional information.
>
> If this flag is specified when calling one of the process creation
>   functions, the handles must be inheritable and the function's
>   `bInheritHandles` parameter must be set to TRUE. For more information,
>   see Handle Inheritance.

The handles returned by `GetStdHandle` are not necessarily inheritable handles, they may be non-inheritable or may be pseudo-handles. In fact they may not exist at all, they may be null or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE -- you need to check for that too.

To get an inheritable handle from a non-inheritable handle or pseudohandle, you need to use `DuplicateHandle`

Comment: using DuplicateHandle did not help, please review source code pasted

Comment: @MichalWegorek In fact they may not exist at all, they may be null or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE -- you need to check for that too

Comment: @MichalWegorek, Also, check *all* your return values and use GetLastError to get the reason if they fail. That's what they are for, so it's likely to be more helpful than asking random strangers to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the parent's stdout/stderr handles directly to the child process. Use `CreatePipe()` to create read/write pipe(s), assign their writing endpoints to the child process stdout/stderr handles, then have the parent process use `ReadFile()` to read from the pipes and write any received data to its own stdout/stderr as needed.  MSDN shows how to use `CreatePipe()` for that:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Why not to pass the parent's stdout/stderr handlers directly? That's not supported on Windows?

Comment: They are probably not inheritable by default.

Comment: But we still should be able to duplicate stdout/stderr as inheriatble and pass those inheritable handlers to STARTUPINFOA structure, am I right?

Comment: I think for GUI type processes these may be nulls and your scheme won't work. Hence using pipes as suggested by Remy is a better approach.